# FBUserSettingsViewController crashes on dismiss just on ios 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, ios6

I'm trying to use `FBUserSettingsViewController` but it's crashing every time I try to dismiss it. I use the following code to display it:

**PS:** it only crashes on ios 6 with this error:

```
// [FBUserSettingsViewController dealloc];

FBUserSettingsViewController *a =[[FBUserSettingsViewController alloc] init];
[a setDefaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone];
[a setDelegate:self];
[a setPublishPermissions:     [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]];
[nav presentViewController:a animated:NO completion:nil];
```

and this to dismiss it:

```
- (void)facebookViewControllerDoneWasPressed:(id)sender{

    _facebook = [[Facebook alloc]
                 initWithAppId:@"176237615850674"
                 andDelegate:self];

    // Store the Facebook session information
    _facebook.accessToken = FBSession.activeSession.accessToken;
    _facebook.expirationDate = FBSession.activeSession.expirationDate;

    if ([nav respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)])
        [nav dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    else [nav dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

there is another question about this topic but there is not any answer there

[The other Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827261/fbusersettingsviewcontroller-crashes-on-dismiss)

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: 0x00136916 in -[FBUserSettingsViewController dealloc]

Comment: @Atif  
0x00136916 in -[FBUserSettingsViewController dealloc]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are bugs in the Facebook iOS SDK. If you take a look at the dealloc method in the source code of FBUserSettingsViewController, you'll notice that they call [super dealloc] before releasing the ivars. Same bug appears in dealloc of FBViewController.

I've fixed these two bugs and pushed my changes to a fork of the facebook-ios-sdk over at GitHub. Take a look at: https://github.com/Tafkadasoh/facebook-ios-sdk

To resolve your problem, simply clone this fork and call "scripts/build_framework.sh" from the command line. Afterwards, you'll find the fixed version of the framework in your "build/FacebookSDK.framework" folder. Fixed the crash for me.